# Why do I need a comma before but if the sentence after is not an independent clause?

Tags: commas

I wrote this sentence in a response.

> I liked the amount of time between the lab and the project but not the amount of time on lectures.

According to Grammarly, I need a comma before the word "but". While that was my initial inclination, I can't figure out why. I don't think it is because the phrase after but is an independent clause or nonessential information. Please let me know if I am wrong about my previous sentence, or I am missing a comma rule. Thanks

Comment: It's optional. Grammar checkers are often overprescriptive or even incorrect. // Didn't _Grammarly_ pick up on the fact that the omission of two different verbs (allowed/left; spent?) is heading towards unacceptability?

Comment: No, it did not. Thanks for the response

Comment: The example you give **does** have an independent clause after *but*; it's simply elided because the meaning is understood from the parallel structure: *[I did not like] the amount of time on lectures.*

Comment: @JasonBassford  That makes it _not an independent clause_.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth Independent clause frequently have parts elided. Elision is *not* a reason to reject its independent status. In fact, it's the opposite. Otherwise, please give a detailed explanation as to why *Yes.* is not a sentence or independent clause.

Comment: @Jason Bassford The punctuation 'rule' assumes unarguable independent clauses; suggesting (especially without any attempt at providing authoritative references) that remnants after deletion must necessarily be punctuated similarly is unscholarly.

Comment: It's all the fault of the word *but* to contrast to a second section -- clause or not. You want your reader to read once and get it, but needing two or three okay? A walk-in closet is not a room, but no door, really? The comma is your door, a simple separator to keep things tidy.

Comment: On the face of it, the example is a sentence of two main clauses: *I liked X but not Y*. However, without context, it appears to be flawed and this makes commenting on a possible comma almost impossible.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth There is no such thing as any kind of universal rule in English, and I've certainly never come across any guidance that talks about *unarguable* independent clauses when it comes to punctuation—which is all style anyway. Additionally, elision is quite common. So, I find any assertion of punctuation rules around elision, or statements of elision prohibiting independent clauses, to be dubious. If you can point to any kind of source for that combined claim, I'd be interested in seeing it.

Comment: I agree with Grammarly here. It's not required by grammar, but it helps to see the structure better when you have multiple conjunctions that serve different roles. "and" joins the objects of "liked", while "but" separates the clauses.

Comment: _I liked the amount of time allowed between the lab and the project[,] but not the amount of time devoted to lectures._ is what I'd prefer. The comma is not mandatory, but I don't like the amount of time between breaths demanded by the commaless version. (As @Barmar says, it also helps in better seeing the structure.)